# Apache Spark merge after updateStateByKey()

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to merge two streams and one of them should be stateful (like static data with not frequent updates):

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test Application").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaStreamingContext context = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(10));
context.checkpoint(".");
JavaDStream<String> dataStream = context.socketTextStream("localhost", 9998);
JavaDStream<String> refDataStream = context.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairDataStream = dataStream.mapToPair(e -> {
    String[] tmp = e.split(" ");
    return new Tuple2<>(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
});

JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairRefDataStream = refDataStream.mapToPair(e -> {
    String[] tmp = e.split(" ");
    return new Tuple2<>(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
}).updateStateByKey((Function2<List<String>, Optional<String>, Optional<String>>) (strings, stringOptional) -> {
    if (!strings.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional.of(strings.get(0));
    }
    return Optional.absent();
});

pairDataStream.join(pairRefDataStream).print();


context.start();
context.awaitTermination();
```

When I write `1 aaa` into the first stream and `1 111` into the second immediately everything works fine, I see result of the merge. But, when I write `1 bbb` into the first stream after one minute I see nothing.

Do I understand correctly what `updateStateByKey()` does? Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`updateStateByKey` does exactly what you ask it for. In particular if current window contains no data (`strings.isEmpty()`) you instruct it to forget (return `Optional.absent();`):

```
if (!strings.isEmpty()) {
    return Optional.of(strings.get(0));
}
return Optional.absent();
```

while what you probably want is to return previous state:

```
if (!strings.isEmpty()) {
    return Optional.of(strings.get(0));
}
return stringOptional;
```